# Would a warp core breach have destroyed the Doomsday Machine?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

The 'Doomsday Machine' uses a hyper-dense alloy that not even a phaser can breach. With this in mind, what kind of damage would a warp core breach do to it? Would it have totally destroyed the machine? Would it have even cracked it?

In Star Trek: Online, a Doomsday Machine is actually [blown into pieces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y18OAydEdqg). I'm aware that this is beta canon so to be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: we already know. An explosion the size of a breach would disable the machine beyond repair apparently.

Comment: @NKCampbell - Except that an antimatter explosion can't harm it, because it emits a field that renders antimatter inert.

Comment: It's worth noting that the explosion of the U.S.S. Constellation was from the impulse engines being overloaded but that destroyed the internal workings not the neutronium hull.  while anything is possible with technobabble fields - rendering antimatter inert would still be quite incredible (maybe the antimatter was stolen for the antiproton beam). A true warp core malfunction with antimatter would be a bigger explosion...but neutronium by definition is tough stuff.  I'd say the only things that would dent it are a black hole or a very large supply of antimatter neutrons eroding the hull.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Which reminds me of what happened in the Larry Niven story "[Flatlander](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216503/what-exactly-makes-a-general-products-hull-nearly-indestructible)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely no damage whatsoever to the shell. Spock already considered that and discounted it.

> **SPOCK:** *Negative, Captain. Its hull is pure [neutronium](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Neutronium). There is **no known way of blasting through it**.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TOS: The Doomsday Machine](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/35.htm)</sup></sub>

The Machine emits some sort of field that renders antimatter inert, so a warp core breach (e.g. a catastrophic matter/antimatter explosion) inside it would have no effect.

> **WASHBURN:** *We made a complete check on structural and control damage, sir. As far as we can tell, something crashed through the deflectors and knocked out the generators. Somehow the antimatter in the warp drive pods has been deactivated.*
>
> **KIRK:** *Deactivated? Scotty, could some kind of general energy dampening field do that, and would the same type of thing account for the heavy subspace interference?*